# How to setSummary of a preference-headers

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, preferencefragment

How can I set a summary of a preference-header on runtime? Even if I put a key in it, `findPreference(key)` will produce a NullPointerException.

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <header android:fragment="PrefActivity$Fragment1"
            android:title="Fragment1"
            android:summary="Summary2"/>
    <header android:fragment="PrefActivity$Fragment2"
            android:title="Fragment2"
            android:summary="Summary2"/>
</preference-headers>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My guess is that you call `invalidateHeaders()` on the `PreferenceActivity`, then return the proper headers (with the updated summary) from `onBuildHeaders()`. `findPreference()` is for preferences, not headers.

Comment: @CommonsWare But how do I return the headers with a dynamic summary in `onBuildHeaders`? At the moment I'm just doing `loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);`

Comment: Find your header in the `List<Header>` and adjust the fields (e.g., `summary`) before returning from `onBuildHeaders()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare I found a solution:

```
@Override
public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
  loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.preference_headers, target);

  for(Header header: target) {
    if (SettingsFragmentTest.class.getName().equals(header.fragment)) {
      header.summary = "New Summary!";
    }
  }
}
```